# Node.js javascript manipulating?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to speed up development by creating a generator using node.js.
I want to be able to manipulate and generate node.js module files, add comments to the files and more.

Example: Generating the API endpoint user:

```
var mod = library.createFile("users");
mod.addFunction("findAll").params([...]).comment("commentSection");
```

Is there such a library or something similar?

Comment: I already tried to achieve the goal by manipulating strings but that is not scalable at all..

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like Protocol Buffers?
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers

There are also compilers for JavaScript available.

Comment: Are you modifying existing modules or creating new ones from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a Node module that writes other Node modules. I don't know of any such module.

I'm not an expert on this area but I think there would be 2 parts to such a module:

**Parser** - Parses existing module files into an Abstract Syntax tree, basically a data structure to represent your code in a structured way. You can then modify this tree to extend your code.

**Code generator** - Takes the AST from above and produces a pretty-printed string (the actual code) which can then be written out to a file.

---

Some of the following may help you:

[Esprima](http://esprima.org/), a parser for Javascript.

[escodegen](https://www.npmjs.org/package/escodegen), an ECMASscript code generator.

[jison](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jison), a A parser generator with Bison's API